# How to create html component in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to create my `html component` in `javascript`. Is there any way I can get this div part from javascript function.

**My html code**

```
<body>
    <h2>My Customers</h2>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr class="header"></tr> 
      <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>
      <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Canada</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Italy</td></tr>
      <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
      <tr><td>France</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I dont understant your qn???

Comment: Which `div part` you wanna get?

Comment: @MantasČekanauskas I am passing on `div` by id by using that id I want to create this table by using javascript.

Comment: multiple ways, out of which the easiest one, but the not cleanest one is to simply use `.innerHTML` property and write your entire table in a string that follows. `document.getElementById("yourDIV").innerHTML = '<table id="someID">'` is an example, just keep piling on.

Comment: Or .append() is also a clean one. Had the PO been using jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my Tic for Tac answer.

```
var myFunction = function(){

        var div = document.getElementById("yourId");
        var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput" + 
          'onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">'+
          '<table id="myTable">'+
          '<tr class="header"></tr>' +
          '<tr><td>Germany</td></tr>'+
          '<tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>'+
          '<tr><td>UK</td></tr>'+
          '<tr><td>Germany</td></tr>'+
          '<tr><td>Canada</td></tr>'+
          '<tr><td>Italy</td></tr>'+
          '<tr><td>UK</td></tr>'+
          '<tr><td>France</td></tr>'+
        '</table>';
      div.innerHTML = myTable;

    }
```

Comment: i earlier used .append() which was jQuery. Then found jQuery was not used

Comment: Yes, but by this way I can add only table. not input.

Comment: What input. ? you did not mension any input in the QN. On the comment below that you said you want to add table inside the div. Look at the first comment on your qn. Try to make us understand what do you really need.

Comment: yes, there is two tag `input ` and `table`. I want to add both. Is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

For appending you can use  [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/1p4kzowt/)

```
function myFunction(){
    var tableStr = `<table id="myTable">
        <tr class="header"></tr> 
        <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>
        <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Germany</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Canada</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Italy</td></tr>
        <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
        <tr><td>France</td></tr>
     </table>`;


     document.getElementById('tableContainer').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', tableStr)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.createElement() like:

```
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);
```

[You can refer this link for more details](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp)

Comment: Ya.. But How I will add table in that

Comment: try something like: 
`function(result){

  var table   = document.createElement("TABLE");  
  var row   = table.insertRow();  
  for( var key in result ){
   
   var cell1   = row.insertCell();
   cell1.innerHTML = result[key];   
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am ttrying this

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery,try:

```
$("#yourdivid").html('Your html code above');
```

with javascript:

```
 var div1=document.getElementById('yourdivid'); 
 div1.innerHTML='Your html code above';
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery: this is an example from my code, the var html just makes sure u don't have to write the same piece of code over and over again.

```
var html = '<div class="swiper-slide">';

html += '<div class="bigIm"><a href="' + url1 + '" target="_blank" class="inner" style="background-image: url(' + img1 + ')">';
html += '<div class="imgCont-b imgCont-b-cov1">';
html += '<a href="' + url1 + '" class="t-icon"><i class="fa fa-' + d1.source.toLowerCase() + ' fa-2x tw-img" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
html += '<span class="tw-text">' + d1.source + '</span>';
html += '<p>' + d1.text + '</p>';
html += '</div>';            
html += '</a></div>';  

html += '<div class="bigIm">';
html += '<div class="half first"><a href="' + url2 + '" target="_blank" class="inner" style="background-image: url(' + img2 + ')">';
html += '<div class="imgCont-b imgCont-b-cov2">';
html += '<a href="' + url2 + '" class="t-icon"><i class="fa fa-' + d2.source.toLowerCase() + ' fa-2x tw-img" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
html += '<span class="tw-text">' + d2.source + '</span>';
html += '<p>' + d2.text + '</p>';
html += '</div>';            
html += '</a></div>';
html += '<div class="half last"><a href="' + url3 + '" target="_blank" class="inner" style="background-image: url(' + img3 + ')">';
html += '<div class="imgCont-b imgCont-b-cov3">';
html += '<a href="' + url3 + '" class="t-icon"><i class="fa fa-' + d3.source.toLowerCase() + ' fa-2x tw-img" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
html += '<span class="tw-text">' + d3.source + '</span>';
html += '<p>' + d3.text + '</p>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</a></div>';
html += '</div>';                                        

html += '</div>';

$('.s1 .swiper-wrapper').append(html);
```

Hope this helps, keep in mind that this code was meant for a website I made, so ur gonna have to change it a bit.